# Can you backup a site collection structure but not include the content?

Tags: site-collection, backup

I have a very large site collection with 10,000s of documents. I want to create a copy of the site collection but not necessarily all of the content. Is there a good way to make a cop of a site collection but not include the content?

I attempted making a site template through the UI but it kept processing for hours the two times I did it and nothing came of it.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

On SharePoint 2007, it was possible before creating a template to exclude content

Site Settings page > Look and Feel section > Save site as template > Include Content section, uncheck the Include Content check box) guess it should be similar for SP2010 / 2013. (edit : indeed, it's like that in SP2010 as well)

[image]

An easy way would be to

- create a full backup of the site (`stsadm -o backup -url {your-site-collection-url} -filename "c:\temp.bak"`)
- empty all non required content from that site collection
- create a backup / template (or export the cleaned site)
- restore the temporary full backup (`stsadm -o restore-url {your-site-collection-url} -filename "c:\temp.bak" -overwrite`)

Third solution, I would investiguate into the [trusty tool made by Chris O Brien](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/) http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/ which might help to get your expected requirement. The tool is open source, I guess it shouldn't be too hard to identify the component responsible for persisting the content and bypassing-it to get only the structure. Would love to have feedback from the master (or check the discussion on codeplex, someone might have thought of this before me !)

Comment: (1) I attempted to do this through the web UI but it kept on spinning with no results. I attempted to do this through SPD but the option was grayed out. (2) I thought about the command line option but there is about 300GB of data / 100+ libraries / 80,000+ documents. I was looking for a way to not duplicate that much content.

Comment: The UI will struggle for sure with 300gb, it's already dead on environment with 4/5gb :( If it's a virtual environment, wouldn't it be faster to ask for a separate copy and do the processing on that snapshot environment (obviously outside of the current network to avoid conflicts). Good luck.

Comment: I agree it would but the goal was to bypass processing the 300GB all together. I can't mark it as an answer because of this but I appreciate your input.

Comment: You could reverse engineer the site template creation to check how they are querying the content of a specific spweb / spsite (all libraries, lists, fields, content types, webs, etc,) and extracting all the meta information to get the structure. Finally I would also investigate into the content deployment API, they might have a way to get what you're expecting.

Comment: edited the reply to also include the tool from Chris O Brien. (mandatory in all SP IT / Dev blackbelt !)