# power shell scritpt to back up a site collection with no content

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

Can you please let me know if we can backup a site collection with out data using poweshell. I know how to do with data, but i dont want with out content,

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sandy I believe this question has been asked and answered. Please see the link.

[Can you backup a site collection structure but not include the content?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52422/can-you-backup-a-site-collection-structure-but-not-include-the-content)

I have used the Chris O'Brien tool and it worked amazingly. You will be able to keep security setting if needed or if you need to move content from one location to the next it will preserve all of the metadata associated with the content ,created, created by, modified, modified by, security customizations and also version history. It is wonderful!

You could also do this through the UI please see this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964489/backup-restore-without-content-in-sharepoint

Comment: I want it through powrshell . Specific reason is we have some alerts in source site. when we restore it it might send alerts

Answer (score 0):

There is not such method available OOTB which will just backup the content of the site collection. But you can think about the following workaround.

- Backup and Restore the site collection,

  - After restoring the site collection, Delete all content from the site collection
  - Now you can use this as backup i.e take another backup of this and use it for future.
- Try to save as template and select the option not include the
  content.
- Lastly, You can try any migration tool i.e metalogix or sharegate etc